# Не применяется стиль к UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, usercontrol

`XAML` код UserControl'а:

```
     <UserControl x:Class="UsersObjects.Styles.UserControls.VectorButton"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UsersObjects.Styles.UserControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="50" d:DesignWidth="50" x:Name="uc">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="local:VectorButton">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:VectorButton">
                        <Button Style="{StaticResource Button.Transparent}" WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" 
                                Command="{Binding Command, ElementName=uc}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding CommandParameter, ElementName=uc}">
                            <Viewbox Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
                                <Canvas Width="25" Height="25">
                                    <Path Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                          Data="{Binding Path, ElementName=uc}" />
                                </Canvas>
                            </Viewbox>
                        </Button>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl>
```

`XAML` код стиля словаря ресурсов Controls.xaml:

```
<Style x:Key="RemoveButton" TargetType="{x:Type uc:VectorButton}">
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="Path" Value="M3,16.74L7.76,12L3,7.26L7.26,3L12,7.76L16.74,3L21,7.26L16.24,12L21,16.74L16.74,21L12,16.24L7.26,21L3,16.74M12,13.41L16.74,18.16L18.16,16.74L13.41,12L18.16,7.26L16.74,5.84L12,10.59L7.26,5.84L5.84,7.26L10.59,12L5.84,16.74L7.26,18.16L12,13.41Z"/>
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
       
    </Style>
```

`XAML` код в MainWindow.xaml:

```
      <Grid>
         <uc:VectorButton Style="{StaticResource RemoveButton}" Margin="220,0,0,40"  Width="30" Height="30"/>
       </Grid>
```

Стиль не применяется, UserControl как будто вовсе отсутствует.

UPD:
CodeBehind UserControl'а:

```
 public partial class VectorButton : UserControl
        {
            public VectorButton() => InitializeComponent();
    
            public Geometry Path
            {
                get => (Geometry)GetValue(PathProperty);
                set => SetValue(PathProperty, value);
            }
    
            public static readonly DependencyProperty PathProperty =
                DependencyProperty.Register("Path", typeof(Geometry), typeof(VectorButton), new PropertyMetadata(Geometry.Parse("M13,14H11V10H13M13,18H11V16H13M1,21H23L12,2L1,21Z")));
    
    
            public ICommand Command
            {
                get => (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty);
                set => SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
            }
    
            public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
                DependencyProperty.Register("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(VectorButton));
    
    
    
            public object CommandParameter
            {
                get => GetValue(CommandParameterProperty);
                set => SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value);
            }
    
            public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty =
                DependencyProperty.Register("CommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(VectorButton));
        }
```

Стиль `Button.Transparent`:

```
 <Style x:Key="Button.Transparent" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border Background="Transparent" Cursor="Hand">
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: А где вы подключаете словарь ресурсов из Controls.xaml? https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/9.3.php

Comment: Я не про пространство имен, а про `ResourceDictionary` в файле `Controls.xaml`. Откройте ссылку выше.

Comment: А, точно, вот в App.xaml `<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/Controls.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>`

Comment: Попробуйте все TargetType переписать вот так `TargetType="{x:Type local:VectorButton}"`

Comment: Не помогло, также UserControl не виден

Comment: А если стиль перетащить из словаря в сам юзерконтрол? Студия ошибки в разметке видит какие? Или нет? Во время работы приложения в отладочной панели вверху окна есть указатель на ошибки?

Comment: Если из словаря перетаскиваю в сам юзерконтрол, то ничего не происходит вроде как.

Comment: Показвайте разметку и кодбихайнд юзерконтрола полностью. Пока не особо понятно, в чем дело. И так же все участвующие в его формировании стили, например этот `StaticResource Button.Transparent`

Comment: Добавил codebehind юзерконтрола и стиль `Button.Transparent`

Comment: `ElementName=uc` - что такое `uc`? Я поэтому и попросил показать полную разметку юзерконтрола.

Comment: Правил, `uc` - само имя юзерконтрола.

Comment: А куда делся стиль из Contols.xaml?

Comment: Вернул, убрал из него анимацию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здесь несколько пробелем

1. Марджины сплющивают кнопку, не используйте никогда марджины из дизайнера

```xml
<Grid>
    <uc:VectorButton Style="{StaticResource RemoveButton}" Width="30" Height="30"/>
</Grid>
```

2. Стиль, назначаемый контролу переопределяет стиль, назначенный внутри контрола. Следовательно, нужно либо назначать только свойства без стиля, либо уходить от `ControlTemplate`.

Получается такая разметка юзерконтрола

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp2.VectorButton"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="50" d:DesignWidth="50">
    <Button Style="{StaticResource Button.Transparent}" 
            WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" 
            DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
            Command="{Binding Command}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding CommandParameter}">
        <Viewbox>
            <Canvas Width="25" Height="25">
                <Path Fill="{Binding Foreground}"
                      Data="{Binding Path}" />
            </Canvas>
        </Viewbox>
    </Button>
</UserControl>
```

Без встроенных ресурсов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, работает!